# How can I add Dynamic combobox in my c# application using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml, combobox

Suppose I want to create UI in which It should display combobox & its items(enum values)dynamically from the database.

suppose my sqlite database is like,

```
Name           datatype          Values                    IsWizard    Screen
Application     enum       0:first,1:second,3:third           1          1
Demo            enum         0:Hello 1:bye                    1          0
```

This is code I wrote,

```
for (int iCount = 0; iCount < ParameterCollection.Count; iCount++)
            {

                objIParameter = ParameterCollection.ElementAt(iCount).Value as IParameter;

                objIParameter.GetColumnValue("Iswizard", out iswizard);
                objIParameter.GetColumnValue("Screen", out screen);
                if (iswizard == 1 && screen == 1)
                {
                    WizardCollection.Add(ParameterCollection.ElementAt(iCount).Key, objIParameter);


                    objIParameter.GetColumnValue(DBEnumName, out enumValues);

                     string[] enumval = enumValues.Split(',');
```

After this how can I add combobox dynamically so that only the values who is having screen ==1 will display with its label and enumvalues inside the combobox

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your data is coming from the database. But I know that ItemsControl is what you are looking for. Which goes something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="2">
            <Grid Margin="3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Label}" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumCollectionName}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      SelectedValuePath="Value" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SampleItems}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
              Margin="10" />
</Grid>
```

I have added sample bindings, you will have to change the bindings as per your data structures and properties depending upon whether you are using MVVM or code behind. But ItemsControl should solve your problem.

Comment: WizardCollection.Add(ParameterCollection.ElementAt(iCount).Key, objIParameter);                                                                                               
I am accessing whole row of my table by using for loop And in the next line I am accessing enumvalues of paticular row                           objIParameter.GetColumnValue(DBEnumName, out enumValues);               So,How can I write the c# ,so that for that element one combobox will create automatically & all the enum values will display on that combobox.next iteration again it will create new combox & do the same